# Is my method of identifying remote ZMQ clients secure?

Tags: authentication

ZMQ provides a CURVE based authorization / encryption system based on certs/keys.  After endpoints are authenticated to the server, they can send an "identity" with each request.  Unfortunately they set this identity themselves, and it's not based on their key.

I don't want to trust that the clients are who they say they are.  So in addition to the ZMQ CURVE security I have the clients hash (sha256) a password they have (unrelated to the ZMQ auth), and send it with each message.  The message itself is encrypted by the ZMQ security.  For each message, the server takes the hash, compares it to what's in the database for the station, and allows the message if the hashes match.

Is this a secure way to verify clients are who they say they are, given it's all encrypted by another (presumed secure) system?

Comment: Well, if you assume the outer system to be secure anyways and to authenticate the sender, there should be no need for additional authentication. Also sending a static token bear little security as an intercepting attacker could just swap out the message it authenticates. This is why _Message Authentication Codes_ always compute a secret function over a message.

Comment: @SEJPM - There seems to be need for additional authentication.  Once the sender is verified by ZMQ each message comes in without a sender address (or a sender-specified address).  So they're authorized to the system, but there's no way to prove which authorized user they are using (the golang implementation) of ZMQ

Comment: ZMQ's CURVE allows mutually authenticated communication meaning the client has keys that it uses to authenticate against server. Have a look at `zauth_configure_curve` in the libcurve library or [configure_curve](https://pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/zmq.auth.html#zmq.auth.Authenticator.configure_curve) in the python library. You can specify a directory of certificates on the server which will contain permitted client keys.

Comment: @lovesh - Right.  But the message sent by authenticated clients do not contain a secure sender address of any kind.  It's just "some authenticated message", which doesn't work when there are multiple clients.

Comment: @horsehair I see.